# jupyter notebookでのインデント幅

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

jypyter notebookで、特に設定はしてないのですが、インデント幅が２になっています。
インデントをスペース4つに変えたいのですが、どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

[公式ドキュメント](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frontend_config.html#example-changing-the-notebook-s-default-indentation)によると、以下のコードをブラウザのJavascriptコンソールで実行するとインデント幅を変更できるようです。

```
var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
var config = cell.config;
var patch = {
      CodeCell:{
        cm_config:{indentUnit:4}
      }
    }
config.update(patch)
```